# How to convert White.Core.UIElements to AutomationElement?

Tags: listview, automation

can i conveert a Listview from TestStackwhite to a Windows form List View? I can get the listview from the UI using he teststack Get method and place it in a listview variable from white. I need to convert it to a windoes.Form.Listview one. I get this error whenever i try to convertt: 
cannot implicitly convert 'Teststack.White.UIItems.Listview' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Listview'

```
  System.Windows.Forms.ListView newList = new TestStack.White.UIItems.ListView;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello MidnightPhantom,

What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why would you want to create a new ListView? 
White can get the element from the application for you, so you can automate user input. 
If you are intending to add new page elements then this should either be behaviour of the application under test, or you can add the elements, and then get them using white.

Can you give me a bit more context so I can help?

Regards,
Rik